# Access files from a large directory Dropbox API

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to access a subset of files from a directory in Dropbox. That directory has more than 25k files (about 200k and growing) and so my initial attempt at building a list of filenames from `client.metadata` isn't workable.

How can one get around this?

I can access the filenames from my local copy and periodically update that list. However, because this is a script that a few people in my lab will use, I hoped for something that did not rely on my local copy of Dropbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the dropbox api, the max amount of files returned from the /metadata api call is 25,000. There is a way to limit the amount of files returned from the api call, but there does not seem a way to list file entries starting from X to Y (like getting entries 100 to 200, then 200 to 300), it seems the only way is to separate these large number of files into folders